# How does PostgreSQL interpret these two join statements?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a question between two very similar PostgreSQL statements:

1. ```
   UPDATE classes SET year = 1
   FROM professors WHERE (professors.class = classes.class)
   AND professors.name = 'Smith'`
   ```

   This one seems to inner join the `classes` table and the `professors` table, and update only the record in `classes` where the corresponding professor's name is Smith.
2. ```
   UPDATE classes c SET year = 1
   FROM classes cl JOIN professors on (professors.class_id = cl.class_id) 
   WHERE professors.name = 'Smith'`
   ```

   This updates every single record in classes. Why is this statement different from the first one?

Comment: From what I understand, the first one is the standard way to carry out and UPDATE-JOIN on two tables in PostgreSQL.

Comment: In the second one `c.*`and `cl.*` are not linked. So every record of `c.` is updated by *every* result-row in the `FROM` term.

Comment: if you want to explicitly refer to `classes` in the `from` clause, add another predicate to the `where` clause: `cl.class_id = c.class_id`. also, seems like your data isn't normalized, i.e. it appears that you expect the join to be equivalent with either `class_id` or `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second, you are referring to `classes` twice.  These are two separate references, and the `c` and `cl` references are not correlated.  In fact, there are no conditions on `c`, so all rows are updated.

You *could* add a correlation condition:

```
UPDATE classes 
     SET year = 1
FROM classes cl JOIN
     professors p
     ON p.class_id = cl.class_id
WHERE p.name = 'Smith' AND cl.class_id = classes.class_id;
```

However, the `JOIN` is unnecessary and the first query is a better approach (for this purpose).